# Email function not working on linux(vps) server

Tags: php, linux, email

I am testing email functionality on a linux (vps) server.
This is the following code which i am using:

```
<?php
  // --- CONFIG PARAMETERS --- //
  //
  $email_recipient = "recipient@demo.com";
  $email_sender = "Sender Name";
  $email_return_to = "sender@demo.com";
  $email_content_type = "text/html; charset=us-ascii";
  $email_client = "PHP/" . phpversion();
 //
 // ------------------------- //

// --- DEFINE HEADERS --- //
//
$email_header = "From: " . $email_sender . "\r\n";
$email_header .= "Reply-To: " . $email_return_to . "\r\n";
$email_header .= "Return-Path: " . $email_return_to . "\r\n";
$email_header .= "Content-type: " . $email_content_type . "\r\n";
$email_header .= "X-Mailer: " . $email_client . "\r\n";
//
// ---------------------- //

// --- SUBJECT AND CONTENTS --- //
//
$email_subject = "Test email subject";
$email_contents = "<html>";
$email_contents .= "<h2>Test Email</h2>";
$email_contents .= "<br><b>Sender: " . $email_sender;
$email_contents .= "<br><b>Recipient: " . $email_recipient;
$email_contents .= "</html>";
//
// ---------------------------- //

$email_result = mail($email_recipient, $email_subject, $email_contents, $email_header);
if ($email_result) echo "Email has been sent!";
else echo "Email has failed!";
?>
```

When i execute the code it takes long time to process and then displays Email has been sent. But the email is never delivered to the recipient.
I have checked the send email path in the php.ini file through phpinfo() function it displays :

```
 sendmail_from  no value    no value
 sendmail_path  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

I am unable to trace out the reason for this.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Pankaj

Comment: The code looks good - it must be a problem with sendmail itself.  Try it from another means or look at the MTA logs (if you have shell access).

Comment: Read `/var/log/maillog`. A successful `mail` call just means the mail was handed over to `sendmail`, not that `sendmail` actually got it off your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual email address as $email_sender; if not working, write 5th parameter in mail() function -fsenderemail@mail.com  (whatever sender e-mail is)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending different recipients? Did you check the spambox? I suggest using PHPMailer, it takes care of headers, etc, makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your sendmail service is running, sometimes you need start it manually for your VPS. it should be something like:

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail start
```

Comment: Hey I have got similar issue it says **-bash: /etc/init.d/sendmail: No such file or directory**